# is there any way of getting all the music I downloaded in the past from Google Play on an old device?

Tags: recovery-mode

I want to know if the hundreds of songs I downloaded in the past on an old device that was stolen or broken can be recovered somehow? do I have really have to download all that again?

Comment: Hi and welcome!  What happened to your old device?  Was it stolen?  Was it broken?

Answer (score 0):

You may hope to recover something from a broken device you still have access to, nevertheless it depends on the kind of malfunction or damage. Anyway, it wouldn't be probably worth the effort.

But I cannot even *imagine* a way to retrieve some songs from a stolen device that would be easier and faster than merely having them downloaded again.